# Excel VBA Range.Value is Variant instead of String

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Macro enabled Excel workbook, and when it launches, it edits some cells and I have a change event, now I want the change event to not run at start up but run when the user makes the changes because when it does, the target.value becomes a variant and hence crashes as am assigning the value to a string variable, here is the code:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H83:H102,K83:K102,N83:N102,Q83:Q102,T83:T102,W83:W102,Z83:Z102,AC83:AC102")) Is Nothing Then
    Dim rowNum As Integer
    rowNum = Target.row
    Dim family As String
    family = Target.Offset(0, -1).Value
    Dim selection As String
    selection = "G" & rowNum & ",J" & rowNum & ",M" & rowNum & ",P" & rowNum & ",S" & rowNum & _
        ",V" & rowNum & ",Y" & rowNum & ",AB" & rowNum
    Select Case family
        Case "FAMILY 1"
            Call validateFamMembers(Target, selection, family, "C64")
        Case "FAMILY 2"
            Call validateFamMembers(Target, selection, family, "I64")
        Case "FAMILY 3"
            Call validateFamMembers(Target, selection, family, "O64")
        Case "FAMILY 4"
            Call validateFamMembers(Target, selection, family, "U64")
        Case "FAMILY 5"
            Call validateFamMembers(Target, selection, family, "C76")
        Case "FAMILY 6"
            Call validateFamMembers(Target, selection, family, "I76")
        Case "FAMILY 7"
            Call validateFamMembers(Target, selection, family, "O76")
        Case "FAMILY 8"
            Call validateFamMembers(Target, selection, family, "U76")
    End Select
End If
```

The code crashes on this line on start up

```
family = Target.Offset(0, -1).Value
```

how do I handle that. Thanks in advance

Comment: Range.Value is supposed to be Variant...not String.  If you need to force it to a string use CStr()

Comment: Please include all of your code

Comment: @CallumDA33 The code is very big but that is the chunk that executes on worksheet change, its that if among a bunch of other ifs but they are independent

Comment: @Rdster I tried using that but still type mismatch when i restart the workbook

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem happens when you select the first column. It explodes, because of the offset, because it cannot reach -1 column after the first.

Edit:

Answer in the comments:
You use Target. Thus, if you select more cells, more cells are in the target. And multiple cells cannot be converted to string, because they are a variant.

Comment: Yep.  Was just about to post that as a comment. The guard clause only makes sure the changed range *contains* cells the OP cares about.

Comment: Does that answer your question though?

Comment: Tried removing the offset function and the problem still isn't fixed

Comment: What is OP first @Comintern

Comment: @lulliezy, can you put the line `debug.print Target.Offset(0, -1).Value` before the line giving you the error and share the answer? There should be a value in the immediate window.

Comment: Type mismatch on  `Debug.Print Target.Offset(0, -1).Value`  @Vityata

Comment: Can you write `debug.print Target.Offset(0, -1).address` and check the value in the printed address?

Comment: The code runs fine at run time but on startup is when it crashes, so If I could get a way to get it to not run only at startup that would be way better

Comment: @Vityata `$E$83:$AB$102` this is the value that is printed

Comment: So, the problem is because you select multiple cells. These multiple cells are a Variant. And not a string. Try selecting one cell.

Comment: I havent really even thought of that because to my knowledge change can only occur on one cell at a time @Vityata

Comment: You use Target. Thus, if you select more cells, more cells are in the target. And multiple cells cannot be converted to string, because they are a variant.